# Switch fragments automatically after time

Tags: android, fragment

I am writing an android app that transforms a nexus 7 tablet into an info panel which should show certain information in fullscreen - no user interaction is necessary.

For each type of information, i created a fragment with the corresponding UI. What i want to achieve is that the main activity switches through the fragments each 5 seconds.

Within each fragment, I implemented a simple callback telling the Activity that its AsyncTask finished getting the data and building the (fullscreen) UI:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).fragmentFinishedLoading();
```

Within my activity, the method looks like this:

```
public void fragmentFinishedLoading(){
    finishedFragments++;

    while(finishedFragments == amountOfFragments){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_A));
        fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_B));
        fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_C));
        fragmentTransaction.show(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_D));
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }
```

*Note that the code above did not yet include functionality to dynamically change which fragment should be hidden or showed.*

My problem: after

```
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and even after

```
fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

the fragments did not change at all. I checked the commit() method and found out that it is async. I know that the Thread.sleep() is bad practice since it freezes the UI, but since no UI interaction is necessary i could live with that. However, since i sent the UI thread to sleep, probably the fragmentTransaction sleeps as well(?)

I am searching for a way to hide/show a certain amount of fragments after a given time without any user interaction - any help on that is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
rguerra's CountDownTimer suggestion did the trick. For the sake of transparency, this is the solution that works for me:

```
public void fragmentFinishedLoading(){
    finishedFragments++;

    if(finishedFragments == amountOfFragments){
        new FragmentTimer(5000, 1000, 1).start();
    }
}

private class FragmentTimer extends CountDownTimer{
    int fId;
    static final int amountOfFragments = 4;

    public FragmentTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval, int fragmentId) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        fId = fragmentId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        if(fId == 1){
            fragmentTransaction.show(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.A_fragment));
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.B_fragment));
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.C_fragment));
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.D_fragment));
        }
        else if (fId == 2){
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.A_fragment));
            fragmentTransaction.show(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.B_fragment));
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.C_fragment));
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.D_fragment));
        }
        else if (fId == 3){
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.A_fragment));
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.B_fragment));
            fragmentTransaction.show(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.C_fragment));
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.D_fragment));
        }
        else if (fId == 4){
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.A_fragment));
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.B_fragment));
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.C_fragment));
            fragmentTransaction.show(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.D_fragment));
        }

        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

        if(fId == amountOfFragments){
            fId = 1;
        }
        else{
            fId++;
        }
        new FragmentTimer(5000, 1000, fId).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: use an AlarmManager (https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) instead of a Thread.sleep. Use a counter to determine which fragment to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use replace Fragment.
example for show R.id.fragment_D

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

         }

         public void onFinish() {
             FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
             ft.replace(R.id.R.id.fragment_D, (Fragment) new FragmentAFragment(), FRAGMENTA_TAG);
             ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
             ft.commit();
         }
      }.start();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: thanks rguerra, your suggestion works flawlessly! I updated my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. You can use a Handler OR Alarm Manager with a PendingIntent OR a Timer.

Based on what your design sounds like I would suggest a ViewPager might be a good choice for managing the transitions between your fragments.

```
Handler mHandler;
public void useHandler() {
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 5000);
}

private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mMyFragmentStatePagerAdapter.myViewPagerIncrementFunction();
        useHandler();
    }
};
```

Cancel it with: `mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);`